# Spring web mvc handler arguments in different methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, kotlin

To begin, I am using Spring WebMVC (5.0.4 through Spring Boot 2.0) with Kotlin (however this question is not related to Kotlin).

I am trying to abstract out some common functionality into an abstract base class that I can re-use across several controllers. For example I do have a `getAll` method in my base class, which is marked as a handler method using `@GetMapping`. Now I would like to call some other (abstract) methods in this class from this `getAll` method. However in those abstract methods the normal parameter-binding mechanisms are not available (e.g. I cannot use `@RequestParam`). Is there a way to go about this problem? How can I access a request parameter in those abstract (non-handler) methods?
I am aware I can use `@RequestParam` with `MultiValueMap<String, String>` to obtain *all* parameters in the `getAll` method, but then I do not have any argument conversion available.

Some code:

```
abstract class MyBaseController {

    @GetMapping fun getAll(@RequestParam allParameters: MultiValueMap<String, String>) {
        // perform some logic
        doStuff()
    }

    abstract fun doStuff()
}

class MyController : MyBaseController() {

    override fun doStuff() {
        // how to obtain e.g. request parameter "ids" as a List<UUID> here?
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do exactly is the question? do you want to add some parameters? do you want to alter some response? depends on your usecase, you might want to take a look at https://github.com/aepfli/springMVCInterception -> but i can give you some ideas if i know what you really want to try to achieve :D

Comment: I am creating an API for internal use. For the `getAll` operation (which will return all resources of a given type in a paginated view) there are several filters possible. For example you could filter articles below a given price by specifying the `maxPrice=123` query-parameter. Now I am trying to extract operations common to all resource types into a base controller, but obviously the types of filters (and therefor the parameters I need to parse) are different per resource.

Comment: Sounds like you want to generate a generic "QueryData" with some values in there, for which you could use the integrated object mapping in java ...(@requestParam QueryData query) which you can always pass on to the doStuff method - but I might miss something here ;)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, I am not aware of how to let spring populate a POJO with request parameters, which you seem to suggest works. The way you suggest in your comment does not work, it complains about a missing parameter.

Comment: Actually it seems `@ModelAttribute` will do that. I will experiment, thanks for pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: yeah sorry, for false information, there is for sure one annotation which is doing that.

Comment: just a theoretical thing -> you could also use a HandlerInterceptor and populate a "RequestScoped" bean -> in this way, your controller, would not need any parameter, you could just autowire the request scoped bean within the abstract controller -> just some thinking, and this is getting into offtopic directions

Comment: `@ModelAttribute` solved this particular use-case, but it only works as a replacement for `@RequestParam`. I would not be able to access e.g. a header value using `@ModelAttribute` + POJO. And I am not sure how I could bind handler-method-style parameters inside a HandlerInterceptor, since that seems to be a rigid interface.

Comment: well you would not be possible to access those parameters in a pojo style, but your request scoped bean would be your "object" -> it would imply manually parsing the request params -> but this could also be a good thing, because you could find a generic approach to cover a lot of fields -> eg parsing parameters name for special syntax at the end ">" "<" "!" to get some kind of comparison, and put that into a map -> but this is getting offtopic. i just like your idea, and it got my head spinning.